# .NET Disable inbound that are not TLS1.2

Tags: .net, wcf, ssl, wcf-security, tls1.2

I developed an WCF that can only be consumed with SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 for clients PCI requirement.

My question is, how can i check the security protocol used by the inbound (code in each method)? How to reject inbound without TLS1.2?

Regards.

Edit: i know how to force the inbound to be TLS12. And i know how to configure server to only allow TLS12. But in testing server i can not do that, so i need to check this on the WCF configuration insted on server conf.

Comment: "But in testing server i can not do that, so i need to check this on the WCF configuration insted on server conf." You are missing the point. You cannot allow a TLS 1.1 / 1.0 handshake to even occur, so this cannot be safely at the application layer. Your PCI QSA will flag that. You should configure your servers to accept 1.2.

Comment: Exactly how did you develop the WCF that can only be consumed with .Tls12?  I'm trying to do that as well, but as soon as Tls1 is disabled at the server level, clients can no longer connect via SOAP over net.tcp.

Answer (score 0):

To restrict the protocol, try setting the global [ServicePointManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```